# Angle of a vector pointing from A to B

Tags: math, vector, atan2

I'm not the best in Maths, but for what I am doing now I need to calculate the angle of the vector which is shown as arrow in the picture below:

[image]

I have a point A and a point B in a 2D plane. I need to calculate the following:

- The angle in which the arrow must be rotated in order to point to B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atan2(yB-yA, xB-xA)`, assuming your library has `atan2`.  Otherwise you need to use `atan`, which will return the correct answer if B is to the right of A, and will be 180 degrees off otherwise.  Also note that the return value is in radians, you can convert radians to degrees by multiplying by `180/pi` if necessary.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Illustrations) has a detailed explanation of the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

arctan((A.y - B.y) / (A.x - B.x)) and note the special case where A.x = B.x